# HttpMessageConverter error handling in inbound gateway

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb, spring-integration

I'm facing a weird behavior when a conversion error occurs using a message converter in my inbound gateway. The idea in the example below is to receive XML payloads (or serialized java), convert them to java objects and respond with the same media type.

Given this configuration:

```
<bean id="converterXml" class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter" />
<bean id="converterSerialized" class="org.springframework.integration.http.converter.SerializingHttpMessageConverter" />

<util:list id="converters">
  <ref bean="converterXml" />
  <ref bean="converterSerialized" />
</util:list>

<int-http:inbound-gateway id="inboundIntegrationGateway" 
  view-name="/integration"
  message-converters="converters" error-channel="errorChannel"
  request-payload-type="MyXmlPojo"
  supported-methods="POST" request-channel="inboundIntegration"
  path="/services/integration"
  reply-timeout="50000">
</int-http:inbound-gateway>
```

If an invalid XML payload (no end tag for example) is submitted, the exception `HttpMessageNotReadableException` raised in the JAXB XML converter is not forwarded in the errorChannel (where I defined a service activator to handle exceptions). Note that this handler works well **after** the payload conversion.

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="errorChannel" ref="exceptionHandlerService"
method="handleException" requires-reply="true" />
```

What am I missing here? Why is the `HttpMessageNotReadableException` not handled by my error handler? Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is the HttpMessageNotReadableException not handled by my error handler?

The `error-channel` comes into force only when we already send `Message` to the downstream flow, but if your incoming HTTP request can't be converted to `Message`, there is still nothing to send to the `error-channel`.

Right, with `convertExceptions = true` we can't just return an exception as is and let some `HttpMessageConverter` to convert it into a reasonable HTTP response. Typically `SerializingHttpMessageConverter` is on the scene.

> Why is this exception not wrapped in a MessageHandlingException and sent to my error handler?

Just because we haven't reached messaging yet. With your problem we are still in the standard Spring MVC environment and Spring Integration is still powerless here during request conversion.

You should consider some solution from Spring MVC for your case: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers

Answer (score 0):

Adding `convert-exceptions="true"` to your `int-http:inbound-gateway`could solve the exception flow problem. This [post](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/115159-exception-propagation-to-the-client-from-spring-integration) has been useful for me.

Comment: It seems to do something as the exception is now written in the response. But there is no converter for that kind of exception.
I now have a MessagingException with : `Could not convert reply: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for type [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException]`. The only solution I found is to create a specific converter for that kind of exception. Why is this exception not wrapped in a `MessageHandlingException` and sent to my error handler?

Comment: @angcap, `convert-exceptions` doesn't have effect if you specify `view-name`. In this case the `<int-http:inbound-gateway>` works like regular `@Controller`. See `convert-exceptions` XSD attribute explanation.